# How to use toastr in Django for success or fail message

Tags: python, django, toastr

I have been using Django message framework to show the success or failure message in my application. But I want the UI to be good so I found out that toastr is a good way to display messages to the user. But I am not sure how to use it. Please guide me through this.

The function below saves the user to the database and when the user info is save a message is displayed:

```
def addSubscriber(request):
    template = 'addSubscriber.html'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = addSubsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save(commit=False)
            f.save()
            messages.success(request, "The Subscriber has been successfully added")
            return redirect('report')

        else:
            messages.error(request, "Sorry the data has not been entered to the database")

    else:
        form = addSubsForm()

    return render(request, template, {'form': form})
```

The following template shows the display of the message:

```
  {% if messages %}
            <ul class="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
                <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 21):

Thanks for this question I was able to implement `toastr` with python, this is a more complete answer that was given by Neeraj Kumar.

In my case, It is much better than materialize, because that CSS kit disrupts my own CSS code and I don't have the time to do CSS debugging.

**First**, in your template, you have to **set the JS files**, example:

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/toastr.css' %}" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/toastr.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Next, inside of the body, **you might put the options for the Toast messages** (These options can be easily created [in the Toastr demo page.](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html)

Finally, **insert this code of block** if you are using the standard tags of the messages framework from django:

```html
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            {% if message.tags == 'success'%}
                <script type=text/javascript>toastr.{{ message.tags }}('{{ message }}')</script>
            {% elif message.tags == 'info' %}
                <script type=text/javascript>toastr.{{ message.tags }}('{{ message }}')</script>
            {% elif message.tags == 'warning' %}
                <script type=text/javascript>toastr.{{ message.tags }}('{{ message }}')</script>
            {% elif message.tags == 'error' %}
                <script type=text/javascript>toastr.{{ message.tags }}('{{ message }}')</script>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

I hope this can be helpful and time saving for other people.

Comment: This is helped me, thnx. Copied messages block in a html called toast-component.html then include it after <scripr .. toastr>.. block. Worked like charm

Answer (score 6):

Add toastr js and css in html code then write below code for showing toastr messages

```
 {% for message in messages %} 
   toastr.{{ message.tags }}("{{ message }}");
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: doesn't work. I don't see any `toastr` message. Instead just the plain error text I send in `message` variable

Comment: @sphoenix Check your console of a browser. I think you will see an error in console that will useful to understand this

Comment: @sphoenix there was an error in the code provided, I fixed it